# Windows UWP CommandBar Disable hiding of labels

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

When a page with a commandbar opens the labels are all displaying like below:

[image]

However as soon as I click on one of the appbarbutton controls the command bar becomes compact and the labels disappear. I need to click on the ellipsis (more) button to see the labels again

[image]

I can't figure out is there a way for the labels to always display and not auto hide when a button is pressed. I've looked at various properties of the commandbar and can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: You need to edit the style in e.g. Visual blend => remove the storyboard which is getting triggered when pressing a button

Comment: Ok thanks - figured it would involve editing the style. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was pretty easy compared to modifying the template. On the OnClosing event of the commandbar call commandbar.Open = true.

I can't take the credit though. Found it here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/521a3c71-ff84-4b7b-b2bf-81bf86d545e9/uwpxamlwindows-10-commandbar-modifying-andor-examining-the-ellipse?forum=wpdevelop